# How a destructor removes a nested stack types?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
class A
{
   char * data;
   ...
   A(){data = new char[50];}
   ~A(){delete [] data;}
};

class B
{
   A a;

   B();
   // default destructor
}

void foo()
{
   B b;
}

int main()
{
   foo();

   // "A.data" still in the heap or no?
}
```

This program is correct and "A.data" will be removed after foo() in main, or will be still exist in the heap?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Question still exist.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will be removed, thru you need to use `delete[]` for arrays. Also you should keep in mind [Rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Or use `std::vector` and dance to the [Rule of Zero](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero)

Answer (score 3):

```
~A(){delete data;}
```

should be

```
~A()
{
    delete[] data;
 }
 //remove the dynamic array
```

In your current code, when main exits, it will call the destructor to release memory and will not exist in heap.

Answer (score 2):

When an object is destructed, the compiler automatically destructs all of the class's non-pointer data members.  So when your `B b` variable goes out of scope, the compiler automatically destructs it, which in turn destructs the `A a` data member since it is not a pointer, which calls `~A()` to free the array.